# Angular Kendo UI Global Access

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm bundling Kendo UI modules in this fashion (simplified for brevity):

**kendo-ui.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    ButtonsModule
  ]
})
```

**ui.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    KendoUiModule
  ]
})
```

**core.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [ UiModule ]
})
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CoreModule ]
})
```

This doesn't work, as the Kendo UI module isn't globally visible.

To get Kendo UI components to work in `LoginComponent`, for example, I have to import `KendoUiModule` into `AuthModule`.

I could shift `KendoUiModule` into a `shared` folder and import it into each module that requires it, but this is an inefficient way of making the components accessible across the application.

It's a UI framework that is core to the entire application after all.

**Question:** What is the best way of handling this so that the code is as lean as possible?

This question is also applicable in other contexts too. For this reason, an effective and efficient solution done in the *Angular way* would offer yet another strategy for the *minimalist* approach without sacrificing functionality.

Comment: To be honest I would rather take apart `shared` and `kendo` modules.

Comment: I don't use a shared module. It's a folder. I hardly ever use shared modules as it's unlikely that all of the modules bundled into a shared module would be required in each feature module that imports it.

Comment: I do not know how you set up your modules but you would want to include it within the component module which uses the component. It might not make sense to create individual modules for `ui` and `kendo` on top of `core`. Either make `core` import all of the required ones within the app or import `kendo` into each componentt

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I would rather take apart `shared` and `kendo` modules.
`Shared` should have things such as `BrowserAnimationsModule`.
`ButtonsModule` I would really just include in either the `app.module` or the module which utilizes the Kendo component.

If you really want to make a module for kendo then create it like this, simply import and export kendo-only stuff:

**kendo-ui.module.ts**

```
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    ButtonsModule, 
    ... 
  ]
  exports: [ 
    ButtonsModule, 
    ... 
  ]
})

export { KendoUiModule }
```

Then create a module for the component which uses kendo and import the module:

**login.module.ts**

```
import { KendoUiModule } from 'kendo-ui.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  imports: [ KendoUiModule  ]
  exports: [ LoginComponent ]
})
```

Alternatively you can just directly import this.

**login.module.ts**

```
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';

const kendoModules = [ButtonsModule, ...]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  imports: [ 
     ...kendoModules
  ]
  exports: [ LoginComponent ]
})
```

And then import the component itself into the app, along with basic stuff like `BrowserAnimationsModule`

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ LoginModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ]
})
```

It is a good practice to create modules as small as possible and only import the most necessary into them. Best would be an extra module for each component.

If you really want them to be globally available it would probably suffice to create a module for kendo and provide it in `app.module.ts`. However this only tthen works for components which `app.module.ts` declares, not the ones it imports. That is why I would rather import them in each component itself.

But in the end its up to how you like it better.

Comment: My code does create a module for Kendo and imports it into AppModule; albeit via UiModule and CoreModule. In my view, BrowserAnimationsModule shouldn't go into SharedModule, since it only needs to be imported into AppModule once. If putting it anywhere, it should be in CoreModule or perhaps UiModule which ends up being imported into AppModule. SharedModule should really be for very common imports such as CommonModule and a few other things. For this reason, I don't use SharedModule but will instead use it as a folder only. Importing Kendo into each feature is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar to what can be done with Angular Material. Perhaps I'm overlooking something simple, but I couldn't get it to work.